# Masking an integer in MIPS (quick and easy)

Tags: binary, mips, masking

I want to input an integer and have it be expressed in both binary and hex. Then I want to move bits 12, 13, 14, and 15 to the least significant bits of $a0, and have the output be expressed as a binary and hex. Here's my program:

```
.data
enter: .asciiz "Please enter your integer:\n"
binaryI: .asciiz "\nHere is the input in binary: "
hexI: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the input in hexadecimal: "
binaryO: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the output in binary: "
hexO: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the output in hexadecimal: "

.text 

prompt: 
li $v0, 4   
la $a0, enter
syscall

li $v0, 5   
syscall
add $s2, $0, $v0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, binaryI
syscall

li $v0, 35  
move $a0, $s2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, hexI
syscall

li $v0, 34  
move $a0, $s2
syscall

addi $t0, $0, 7
srl $s0, $s2, 12
and $s0, $s0, $t0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, hexO
syscall

li $v0, 35
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, binaryO
syscall

li $v0, 34
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, 1   
add $a0, $0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

For the integer 1006460, for example, the inputs and hex output work perfectly, but the binary output has an extra 5 at the end. The error I get is this:

Here is the output in binary: 0x000000055

What may have caused this extra 5 to be at the end of the output?

Answer (score 0):

How silly of me. I should have deleted

```
li $v0, 1   
add $a0, $0, $s0
syscall
```

from my code.